# How setTimeout function is working in this case?

Tags: javascript, settimeout

```
<body>
   <input type="text" value="10" id="txtBox" /><br/><br/>
   <input type="button" value="Start Timer" onclick="startTimer('txtBox')" />
   <input type="button" value="Stop Timer" onclick="stopTimer()" />
   <script type="text/javascript">
      var intervalId;      
      function startTimer(controlId)
      {
          var control = document.getElementById(controlId);
          var seconds = control.value;
          seconds = seconds - 1;
          if (seconds == 0)
          {
              control.value = "Done";
              return;
          }
          else
          {
              control.value = seconds;
          }
      
          intervalId = setTimeout(function () { startTimer('txtBox'); }, 1000);
      }
      
      function stopTimer()
      {
          clearTimeout(intervalId);
      }
   </script>
</body>
```

I am new to JavaScript. I was going through some tutorial, the above code snippet I came across, which works completely fine for starting a `countdown` timer from `10 to 0` in every `1000 millisecond` interval. I am confused that how `setTimeout()` is calling the function repeatedly, when it is supposed to call the function only once after waiting 1000 millisecond.

Comment: Because `setTimeout` is **inside** the function it is calling. Here is an advice: do a proper indentation in your code. When you indent it correctly, you can better see what's inside what.

Comment: Everytime `startTimer` gets called, it schedules another call in 1000ms at the end.

Comment: yuou have added `setTimeout()` inside the `startTimer()` so whenever u call `startTimer()`  .. `setTimeout()` get called..

Answer (score 0):

The `startTimer()` function will be called by the `setTimeout()` function. Then when the `startTimer()` function is executing, it will call the `setTimeout()` function again. So it is a lot like a loop.
 You can also use `setInterval` instead:

```
intervalId = setInterval(function(){
    startTimer('txtbox');
}, 1000);
```

use it outside the `startTimer` function. It will call the `startTimer` function once every 1000 milliseconds repeatedly.

Comment: It's not a recursive function.

Answer (score 0):

`function startTimer(){...}` is a named function. One advantage of named function is that it call itself from inside its body. The code you shared is exploiting this concept & the code inside `setTimeout` is calling the same function `startTimer`

```
intervalId = setTimeout(function() {
        startTimer('txtBox');
      }, 1000);
```